# Twilio stuck setting up a Twilio Programmable Wireless SIM Card for SMS

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm new.
I'm following this simple guide:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/01/setting-up-a-twilio-programmable-wireless-sim-card-for-sms-and-phone-calls.html

I bought a phone number and Narrowband SIM - Starter Pack and activated one.

I'm stuck here:
-Select TwiML
-Click the red “+” button to the left of the SMS URL
-You should see a popup appear with a TwiML template for routing messages as seen in this image

I only see "TwiML Apps" to click on. I can't get the pop up to show up.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see you mentioned, `Narrowband SIM` which are designed for low-power long use devices, so that use case defined in that blog above isn't specific to that type of SIM. Twilio offers another SIM which does provide voice in the US but that again isn't its primary use case.